# Printing timestamp with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

When I look at my rails console(at record from database) my date looks like this :

created_at: `"2013-05-17 14:54:34"`

When I do `MyClass.created_at` it prints :

```
Fri, 17 May 2013 14:54:34 UTC +00:00
```

How do I get date printed like this `"2013-05-17 14:54:34"` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `MyClass` respond to the method `created_at`?

Comment: `strftime` is the built-in way to do it. Its syntax is intense, though. Check out [stamp](https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp#usage) if you would like to format dates & times in a human-friendly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Rails environment, to_formatted_s can also be used:

```
MyClass.created_at.to_formatted_s(:db)
```

This different arguments that can be passed to to_formatted_s are [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_formatted_s).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MyClass.created_at.strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

if you are getting right answer for date in MyClass.created_at

Comment: You can shorten the format string by using `%F` and `%T`, see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)